# hide/show html div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

my question hasn't already been asked because i don't want to know how i can hide/show a div element in html, but i would like to know why my method doesn't works.
My javascript functions are executed even though i used "onclick" event.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>show&hide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stile.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="p1">show</button>
    <button id="p12">hide</button>
    <div id="scritta" class="hiddendiv">text to show</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function show() {
        document.getElementById('scritta').className='visiblediv'; 
      }

      function hide() {
        document.getElementById('scritta').className='hiddendiv'; 
      }

      function inizializza() {
        var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
        p1.onclick = show();
        var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
        p2.onclick = hide();
      }

      window.onload= inizializza;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my css class:

```
.hiddendiv {
   display:none;
}
.visiblediv {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: your inizializza() function is being called or not???

Comment: yes, it's called with "window.onload" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

1. The ID for your second button should be `p2` instead of `p12`.
2. You have to assign your event handlers like this
   `p1.onclick = show;`
   instead of like this
   `p1.onclick = show();`

Adding the brackets will execute the method, instead of binding it as an event handler.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5Rr/).

Comment: thanks, it's works with your suggestion. I didn't know this function of the brackets...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your second button has id "p12", but in the JavaScript code you are searching for an element with id "p2".  An easy way to find such bugs is to use the developer console found in many browsers (e.g. in the menu "Developer > JavaScript Console" in Google Chrome).  For your code, the console shows the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

together with an indication that the problem occurs on line 22 of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code you are searching an element with id=p2, but you have this html `<button id="p12">hide</button>` try to change it to `<button id="p2">hide</button>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `p1.onclick = show()`. You don't need to call a function, so fixed variant:

```
p1.onclick = show;
p2.onclick = hide;
```

Or use anonymous functions:

```
p1.onclick = function() {
    show();
}
p2.onclick = function() {
    hide();
}
```

And better use `addEventListener` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Change `inizializza` to this one:

```
function inizializza() {
   var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
   p1.onclick = show;
   var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
   p2.onclick = hide;
}
```

and buttons definition to the following:

```
<button id="p1">show</button>
<button id="p2">hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just show the text while you click on the "show button" and hide on click in "hide button" you don't want to complicate the script. just add show() in show button and hide() in hide button as onclick event. here is the code.

```
<style>
    .hiddendiv {display:none;}
    </style>
```

function show() {document.getElementById('scritta').style.display="block";}
function hide() {document.getElementById('scritta').style.display="none";}

I am not sure that it whether it is your need... however check it... best wishes...